# System.out.print with // prints the code Blue. What is the meaning of this?

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat

`System.out.println(TAG + " //METHOD_STARTED// - //start_firebase_and_get_userID//");`

Why if I write these in my app, it comes in blue in the console after the //?

[image: Console screenshot]

Comment: It at least doesn't appear to be Android Studio related, there doesn't seem to be a coloring rule for blue when `//` is used.  Otherwise blue is notated as 'verbose' logging

Answer (score 3):

It appears to be mistaking it for a hyperlink.

`//METHOD_STARTED//` *is* a valid [protocol-relative URL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Protocol-relative_URL) (domain names don't have to have dots if they're on your local network), and it seems that Android Studio/IntelliJ's link detection is falling for it.  Of course, it's not valid in this case, because there's no protocol in the log output for it to be relative to, so really this is a bug.